# Dynamically Set ContentSize of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that has been created programatically. Upon creation of the collection view, I would like to dynamically define the collection view height based on the number of cells that it must hold. I do not want to enable scrolling of the collection view itself, rather this collection view is being added as a subview to a view that is contained inside a vertical `UIScrollView`.

For example, if the `UICollectionView` has 10 `UICollectionViewCells`. It might have a height of 200.0f, but if it has 20 cells it might have a height of 300.0f, and so on.

I have attempted to accomplish this by following the Apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html), overriding the `collectionViewContentSize` method.

Although this method does return a valid `CGSize` when it is called, when I instantiate the collection view, its `frame` is always set to zero.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
//subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@interface LabelLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger cellCount;
@property (nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets sectionInset;
@property (nonatomic) CGSize itemSize;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minimumLineSpacing;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minimumInteritemSpacing;

@end

- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

return self;
}

-(void)prepareLayout
{
    [super prepareLayout];
    _cellCount = [[self collectionView] numberOfItemsInSection:0];
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(245.0f, 45.0f);
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20.0f;
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
   CGFloat collectionViewWidth = 550;
   CGFloat topMargin = 10;
   CGFloat bottomMargin = 10;
   CGFloat collectionViewHeight = (self.cellCount * (self.itemSize.height +    
   self.minimumLineSpacing*2)) + topMargin + bottomMargin;

   //THIS RETURNS A VALID, REASONABLE SIZE, but the collection view frame never gets set with it!
   return CGSizeMake(collectionViewWidth, collectionViewHeight);
 }

//create collectionView in viewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self makeLabels]; //determines the number of cells

    LabelLayout *layout = [[LabelLayout alloc]init];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];   
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
}
```

Additionally, when I explicitly define a static frame for the `UIcollectionView`, it is created as expected, so I know that my only issue is in using the `collectionViewContentSize` method.

So my question is, how can I dynamically set the height of my `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Use storyboards sir, your life will become easier.

Comment: @AdamWaite , please tell me how can i do it, i am using storyboard for it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A collection view *is* a scroll view, so your `-collectionViewContentSize` method is determining the size of the content, not the size of the overall view. You'll need to set the collection view's `bounds` or `frame` property to set the size of the collection view itself.

You might also want to set it's `scrollEnabled` property to `NO` while you're at it.

Comment: got it, thanks. I ended up doing this to make it work:        CGFloat   cellHeight = 45;
CGFloat height = [self.labels count] * cellHeight;
CGFloat width = 550;
_collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method.

In Swift:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
    return CGSizeMake(250, 150);
}
```

In Objective-C:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(250, 150);
}
```